# Is it possible to use different Japanese fonts on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

As far as I can tell, the default Japanese font on Stack Exchange is some kind of Mincho font. Is there a way to use other fonts such as Meiryo or Kyokasho fonts?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible"? Are you asking about using custom browser scripts that allow you to change the way fonts are displayed on your computer, or about changing the font for everyone?

Comment: For the first option, take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/how-to-change-all-fonts-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: I meant changing it so that everyone sees a particular font. For example, let's say I wanted my post to be in MS Gothic and it would be displayed that way for everyone. But I guess that is not such a good idea. I will have a look at the link you posted, thanks.